# react-router dynamic segments crash when accessed

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route configuration that looks like this (showing only the parts that I think may be relevant):

```
var React = require('react');

var Router = require('react-router');
var { Route, DefaultRoute, NotFoundRoute } = Router;

var routes = (
    <Route handler={AppHandler}>
        <DefaultRoute handler={HomeHandler}/>
        <Route name='home' path='/home' handler={HomeHandler}/>
        <Route name='settings' path='/settings/?:tab?' handler={SettingsHandler}/>
        <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFoundHandler}/>
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('application'));
});
```

Now, on my Settings react file, I have the following:

```
var Settings = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Router.State],
  render: function() { ... }
});
```

If I access the `host.local/settings` and log `this.getParams()` everything works fine and the file renders showing me `Object {tab: undefined}` in the console. But as soon as I try `host.local/settings/user` - where I expected the console to return something like `Object {tab: 'user'}` -, the whole thing crashes somewhere and just starts throwing `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in the console.

React is still young and therefore the errors are rather vague in many situations.

I've followed the specifications provided on the **[Path Matching Guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/path-matching.md)** and it seems pretty standard, so I can only assume it's a problem with react-router itself or am I missing something?

---

### Update

tl;dr: It's not a problem with react-router.

**Long version:**

Apparently, it turns out the issue is not on ReactJS neither React-Router themselves. It involves mostly a bug on **gulp-webserver** (which I'm using for developing using proxies to connect separate projects running in parallel) and triggers an error when URLs are typed directly on the browser instead of being accessed through a link.

I did a test and it works fine when navigating, but crashes when accessed directly as described on **[this github issue](https://github.com/schickling/gulp-webserver/issues/54)**, which basically renders my functional deeplink tests unviable, but should work when in production.

---

### Update 2

tl;dr: It's not a problem with gulp-webserver either.

In my case, it was related to `relative` and `absolute` paths and **not any issue with gulp-webserver** as mentioned before. To be more specific, I had to make sure your script and CSS references were absolute so that it doesn't try to find them in the path you're typing in the URL.

e.g.:

You have two URLs: `/settings` and `/settings/account`. In that case, if you have your script inclusion in the fallback file being something like `<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>`, the server will return a 404 for it, since there's no file in `/settings/scripts/main.js`.

Dumb of me, but in case anyone else falls for that, I hope this helps.

---

Comment: I was about to venture into the darkest of rabbit holes. You are a true hero, preventing this scenario: http://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 48):

Thanks for your analysis, it helped me to realize it wasn't an issue with React Router but my own paths.

I added `<base href="/" />` into the `<head>` of my `index.html` and it worked (:

**Edit for React Router 3:**

Since early 2016, React Router will show a warning when you set `<base>`:

```
Warning: Automatically setting basename using <base href> is deprecated 
and will be removed in the next major release. The semantics of <base href>    
are subtly different from basename. Please pass the basename explicitly in the
options to createHistory
```

It's better to do something like this instead:

```
const history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
    basename: '/'
});
```

Comment: @YangShun did you manage to get this working server side as well?

Comment: @shouvik sorry I did not try this on server side but it should also work.

Comment: hmm, not really running into issues. Just posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171647/dynamic-segments-using-basename-on-the-server-side-react-router

Comment: Thanks! I solved my problem with this. However, some of my colleagues did not need to use this trick to make it work. We use the same browser version and same `yarn.lock`. May I know what could interfere with the behavior of `base`?

Comment: @LilE a lil bit late but maybe your colleages had the resource import path as a full path e.g.: "/js/jquery.js", bc this error only occurs when import path is relative e.g.: "js/query.js" (note missing "/" at the beginning)

Answer (score 1):

I am not encountering the error that you're seeing. It seems like your code is all right, so it's probably something that you didn't paste.

giving the information, I've build a quick project according to your spec and here's my setup

```
'use strict';

var React           = require('react'),
    Router          = require('react-router'),
    AppHandler      = require('./pages/app.js'),
    HomeHandler     = require('./pages/home.js'),
    SettingsHandler = require('./pages/setting.js'),
    NotFoundHandler = require('./pages/not-found.js'),

    Route           = Router.Route,
    NotFoundRoute   = Router.NotFoundRoute,
    DefaultRoute    = Router.DefaultRoute,
    Routes;

Routes = (
    /* jshint ignore:start */
    <Route handler={AppHandler}>
        <DefaultRoute handler={HomeHandler}/>
        <Route name='home' path='/home' handler={HomeHandler}/>
        <Route name='settings' path='/settings/?:tab?' handler={SettingsHandler}/>
        <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFoundHandler}/>
    </Route>
    /* jshint ignore:end */
);

Router.run(Routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler, state) {
    React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

I'm skipping the home and not found since those are not the problem,
here's my setup in settings.js

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react')
    Router = require('react-router');

var Setting = React.createClass({

    mixins: [Router.State],
    componentDidMount: function() {
        //console.log(this.getParams());
    },

    render: function() {
        /* jshint ignore:start */
        console.log(this.getParams());
        return (
            <div>this is setting</div>
        );
        /* jshint ignore:end */
    }

});

module.exports = Setting;
```

hope these will help

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for taking the time.
The code you provided unfortunately replicates the exact issue on my machine. Did it work for you?

I'm starting to wonder whether it may be some dependency gone wrong...

Comment: it is working on my end as {tab: 'user'}, what version of react-router are you using? also the react version?

Comment: Hi, forgot to post the info about the versions. ReactJS is **0.12.2** and React-Router is **0.11.6**.
I tried running a **`npm install`** and **`npm update`** to be on the safe side, but no luck. Apparently it's not my lucky week.

Comment: Hi Jim, I've updated the question with the answer to the problem. Thanks for your help!