# Nested Routes and browserHistory

Tags: react-router

I'm having some trouble working with browserHistory and nested routes. The main issue is entering a path directly or refreshing the browser: works perfectly for non-nested routes but not for nested routes.

I'm using webpack-dev-server locally and I am using the history-api-fallback flag:

- Without the history-api-fallback flag: any route I type in directly or refresh on gives me "Cannot GET /..." rendered in the browser window. This is expected behavior.
- With the history-api-fallback flag: non-nested routes work fine typed in directly or refreshed on but nested routes do not. I don't get the same react-router(?) error rendered in the browser window but I do get 404s in the console, it looks like the browser is trying to load the webpack bundle from one level up in the path (e.g. if I'm on /schools/edit and I hit refresh, the browser tries to load the webpack bundle.js from /schools/ and 404s out).

I have a very simple setup with only a couple of nested routes. All components are simply rendering a div with text for now (with the exception of App and Schools which both also output this.props.children to render their child routes).

My routes:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />

    <Route path="schools" component={Schools}>
      <IndexRoute component={SchoolManager} />
      <Route path="manage" component={SchoolManager} />
      <Route path="edit" component={SchoolEditor} />
    </Route>

    <Route path="*" component={Home} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Webpack config:

```
entry: [
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  './app/scripts/main.js',
  './app/styles/main.scss'
],
devtool: 'source-map',
output: {
  path: './build/',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0,presets[]=react'],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.(html|png)$/,
      loader: 'file?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=./app'
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
    }
  ]
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
],
watchOptions: {
  poll: true
}
```

NPM script to start webpack dev server (run from inside a Vagrant vm):

```
webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --progress --colors --inline --hot --history-api-fallback
```

To summarize:

- `<Link>`ing to any of the paths above works fine, /schools, /schools/manage, /schools/edit, etc.
- Typing in or refreshing on /schools works fine.
- Typing in any of the other nested paths (/schools/manage, /schools/edit) or refreshing on them does not work.

I realized as I was typing this out that 'schools' is also technically a nested route but seems to work fine, so it's likely there's something else going on. Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: can you provide webpack / devserver config

Comment: @Utro Added webpack config and npm script, thanks

Comment: it's strange that  <link to="/schools/manage"/>works , but Typing in- doesnt work, Could you provide a repo for testing purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After resigning myself to hashHistory for the longest time, finally came across the solution for nested routes.  Just had to change the bundle script src from `bundle.js` to `/bundle.js`.  The leading `/` ensures that the browser will load bundle.js from the root directory.  Credit to Fastas: [Unexpected token < error in react router component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718481/unexpected-token-error-in-react-router-component)