# react js + react router errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hi I am trying to do this tutorial, but i get errors right after I add `react-router`, the code works prior to adding `react-router` to it:
Uncaught SyntaxError:

> - Unexpected token <
>
>   - and Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for    built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>       but got: undefined.

Any clues? Thanks for helping me.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import css from './css/style.css';
import { Router, Route, Navigation } from 'react-router';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="catch-of-the-day">
        <div className="menu">
        <Header tagline="Fresh Seafood Market" />
        </div>
        <Order />
        <Inventory />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

//header
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header className="top">
        <h1>Catch
          <span className="ofThe">
            <span className="of">of</span>
            <span className="the">the</span>
          </span>
          Day</h1>
        <h3 className="tagline"> <span>{this.props.tagline}</span></h3>
      </header>
    )
  }
}

class Order extends Component  {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Order</p>
    )
  }
}

class Inventory extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Inventory</p>
    )
  }
}

class StorePicker extends Component  {
  render(){
    return (
      <form className="store-selector">
        <h2>Please Enter A store</h2>
        <input type="text" ref="storeId" required />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

//Routes
const routes = (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={StorePicker}/>
    <Route path="/store/:storeId" component={App}/>
  </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('main'));
```

Comment: More information is required. If nothing else, how are you transpiling your JSX?

Comment: Where's your index.html file? And where is the error popping up? In webpack?

Comment: Usually you add a history to the Router, too. `<Router history={history} />`
Where you should import it as `import { browserHistory as history } from 'react-router'; // or use hashHistory`

Comment: its all set with some boilerplate (I think JSX is transpiled with babel? or so i see in the node modules) , actually it worked before the router stuff, all the components were OK and rendering before. It has to be somwhere in the router import/ implementation in the code or I dont know = of course I am noobie anyhow.

Comment: Where is the "unexpected token <" located? The error log should point out where in the code it is.

Comment: Its gonna sound unbelievable but it doesnt point anywhere, I cant click it I cant get any information about it, but to make it even more confusing I will add that this error occurs even prior to router stuff and doesnt affect rendering the components and IMO acts like its not actually doing anything.

Comment: not sure whether it will work in ur case or not try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718481/unexpected-token-error-in-react-router-component/35302590#35302590

Comment: Oh sorry the unexpected token < refers to <!doctype html> I must have been blind to not actually see it. Sorry for that...