# React-router v4 - cannot GET *url*

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, localhost, react-router

I started to use react-router v4. I have a simple `<Router>` in my app.js with some navigation links (see code below). If I navigate to `localhost/vocabulary`, router redirects me to the right page. However, when I press reload (F5) afterwards (`localhost/vocabulary`), all content disappear and browser report `Cannot GET /vocabulary`. How is that possible? Can somebody gives me any clue how to solve that (reload the page correctly)?

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Vocabulary from './pages/Vocabulary'

const appContainer = document.getElementById('app')

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/vocabulary">Vocabulary</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/vocabulary" component={Vocabulary} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>,
appContainer)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually)

Answer (score 314, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Webpack. If so, adding a few things to your webpack config should solve the issue. Specifically, `output.publicPath = '/'` and `devServer.historyApiFallback = true`. Here's an example webpack config below which uses both of ^ and fixes the refresh issue for me. If you're curious "why", [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually) will help.

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

I wrote more about this here - [Fixing the "cannot GET /URL" error on refresh with React Router (or how client side routers work)](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/)

Comment: worked by added  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

Comment: And don't use HtmlWebpackPlugin with index.html as a template as the bundle is not injected on refreshing on a route. Insert the bundle.js script directly as a script tag in the index.html.

Comment: It worked for me just addding `devServer {  historyApiFallback: true }`

I already had  `publicPath: '/'` configured

Comment: Thank you! In many sources they all say add historyApiFallback but they had never mentioned about output.publicPath = '/'. I did not configured my publicPath so i couldn't solve my problem until see your post.

Comment: This worked for me as well adding `historyApiFallback: true` to the devServer.

Comment: I have both `historyApiFallback: true` and `publicPath: /`, but it's not working... also I'm using express-server... do I need to configure express instead of webpack?

Comment: +1 from me and do not forget to restart server (if you have hotload enabled) every time you change webpack.config.js.

Comment: And what about production config?

Comment: @SKLTFZ What is the solution if i am not using webpack?

Comment: How to fix this without setting ```historyApiFallback: true```?

Comment: It works on devServer. but after build Its not works :(

Comment: historyApiFallback is enough for me

Comment: A more detailed description of this solution and what happens behind the scenes https://ui.dev/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh

Comment: Don't forget to restart the app. To do another start, after changing the webpack.config.js. npm start.

Answer (score 17):

Just to supplement Tyler's answer for anyone still struggling with this:

Adding the `devServer.historyApiFallback: true` to my webpack config (without setting `publicPath`) fixed the 404/Cannot-GET errors I was seeing on refresh/back/forward, but only for a single level of nested route.  In other words, "/" and "/topics" started working fine but anything beyond that (e.g. "/topics/whatever") still threw a 404 on refresh/etc.

Just came across the accepted answer here: [Unexpected token < error in react router component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718481/unexpected-token-error-in-react-router-component) and it provided the last missing piece for me.  Adding the leading `/` to the bundle script src in my `index.html` has solved the issue completely.

Answer (score 12):

It worked for me just need just addding `devServer { historyApiFallback: true }` is OK, not need use `publicPath: '/'`

usage like:

```
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
```

Answer (score 9):

If your application is hosted on a static file server, you need to use a  instead of a .

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render((
  <HashRouter>
    <App />
  </HashRouter>
), holder)
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4.1.1/FAQ.md#why-doesnt-my-application-render-after-refreshing

Comment: The article you've referenced was really helpful because I was using express.js. This code from the article gave me the hint and solution of accepting different URL aside from the "/" since it has an asterisk as an argument of get() function.


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'))
})

Answer (score 7):

Works with React-router v6 and Webpack 5
(https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devservermagichtml):

```
devServer: {
   magicHtml: true,
   historyApiFallback: true,
},
plugins: [
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
      publicPath: '/',
   })
]
```

Comment: Up to dated solution 

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue, what fixed it for me was editing my `package.json` file, and under `scripts: {`

```
"build": "webpack -d && copy src\\index.html dist\\index.html /y && webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --port 3000"
```

at the end of my webpack `build` code I added `--history-api-fallback`
this also seemed like the easiest solution to the `Cannot GET /url` error

Note: the next time you build after adding `--history-api-fallback` you will notice a line in the output that looks like this (with whatever your index file is):

> 404s will fallback to /index.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Express (not Webpack), this worked for me..

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/your/index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Where do you have to write this code ? In which file of the backend ? I have app.js , index.js and then inside controllers different routers. I am using express.js. Also about the path of index.html. Which path are we talking about ? I have the frontend build folder inside my root directory of backend.

Answer (score 2):

I also had success with this by adding ... `historyApiFallback: true`

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    watchContentBase: true,
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    historyApiFallback: true
}
```

Comment: Where do i add this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Webpack check your configuration in part of server configuration for the 
"contentBase" attribute. You can set by this example:

```
devServer: {
    ...
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '../')
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer, if you are using the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and still getting errors double check the `filename` property. If you are setting the `filename` specifically for production then you will need to add a condition to set the `filename` contingent on the `WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER` variable. Please see the example below:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   template: './src/index.html',
   filename: process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER ? 'index.html' : PROD_HTML_PATH,
})
```

Comment: what's `PROD_HTML_PATH` ?

Comment: It is an arbitrary variable name for the path you would want to use for production. The variable could be named anything @7urkm3n

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using webpack. You need to add 

        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
          }
        
        Example :: 
        
        var path = require('path');
        var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
        
        module.exports = {
          entry: './app/index.js',
          output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: 'index_bundle.js',
            publicPath: '/'
          },
          module: {
            rules: [
              { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
              { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
            ]
          },
          devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
          },
          plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
              template: 'app/index.html'
            })
          ]
        };
```