# Can't navigate to react-router-dom URL's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

There are a few topics on SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209666/react-router-v4-cannot-get-url) which recommends changing Webpack and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually) that recommends setting up a catch-all.

I am using `react-router-dom` for three routes; similar story to the rest of the questions on here, the `/` path works but neither `/cars` or `/about` does.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link} from 'react-router-dom';


const Home = () => (
  <h1>Home</h1>
)

const Car = () => (
  <h1>Cars</h1>
)

const About = () => (
  <h1>About</h1>
)

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path="/cars" component={Car}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I have tried adding a `publicPath` and `historyApiFallback` into my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index.jsx'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/,loader: 'babel-loader',exclude: /node_modules/},
      {test: /\.jsx$/,loader: 'babel-loader',exclude: /node_modules/}
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
}
```

But as soon as I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/cars` I get a `Cannot GET /cars` message on the browser and a load of errors similar to this:

```
Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAGz8ABEAAAAA09gAAQABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABHREVGAAABgAAAAC8AAAA0AsQC9UdQT1MAAAGwAAATuAAANLwBEyF1R1NVQgAAFWgAAAIWAAAEZqfk0PVPUy8yAAAXgAAAAFAAAABgaNCCw2NtYXAAABfQAAABkwAAAkQk8AV7Y3Z0IAAAGWQAAABiAAAAugGiQq9mcGdtAAAZyAAABZcAAAvNb3/BHGdhc3AAAB9gAAAACAAAAAgAAAAQZ2x5ZgAAH2gAAESvAAB8yu28l3FoZWFkAABkGAAAADYAAAA2BmibVWhoZWEAAGRQAAAAIAAAACQHMQRzaG10eAAAZHAAAAJDAAAEImBmMbxsb2NhAABmtAAAAhoAAAIaflxdR21heHAAAGjQAAAAIAAAACACjgzgbmFtZQAAaPAAAACdAAABKBQEL8lwb3N0AABpkAAAAsMAAAS9pi3QFXByZ...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Comment: I tried your code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vhjqgb) and that works for me. I understand it could be an issue with your webpack but just to point out that there's nothing wrong with the code itself.

Comment: Thanks @Rowland - I've just figured it out so will post the answer as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically after trying to figure this out on my own for 30 minutes, getting frustrated and posting on SO; I figured it out 2 minutes after...!

The configuration I added into my `webpack` file was pointless; seeing as I am serving my files using `express`

The `catch-all` method was what I needed, but I had done it wrong. You have two options. Do a proper "catch all" and send **everything** to the HTML file...

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(appRootPath + '/public/index.html');
});
```

or, if like me, you want to only send a specific endpoint, so you can still manage 'other things' you can...

```
app.get('/react*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(appRootPath + '/public/index.html');
});
```

A specific mention, because this is what tripped me up, make sure you do `/react*/` and not `/react/*`

I could then update my Routes to the following and browse to them directly...

```
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/react" component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path="/react/car" component={Car}/>
      <Route path="/react/about" component={About}/>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[image: Heres an example where I typed in a random URL]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it by changing my server implementation to use express with "catch all and send to index.html" as suggested by OmisNomis.

Adding here my server.js code for anyone who has no previous knowledge of express

```
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")
const app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname))
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html')))
app.listen(8080)

console.log("Running at Port 8080")
```