# Cannot GET "/About" with react-router v4 (Production Help)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I've been reading over all the docs for react-router-dom (v4), and tons of Stack Overflow questions with my same error, but A) They leave a lot of unanswered holes and B) They seem to all be suggesting a development only fix, so I'm hoping to see what people are actually doing in PRODUCTION for this simple scenario and C) I'm probably doing something stupid and the answers aren't working for me, with the error "Cannot GET /about" rendering with no errors in the console.

I'm using Express, React, Node and using Webpack for compiling. I can successfully reach my homepage, and clicking any links takes me to the appropriate components, but manually typing in the URL breaks this, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209666/react-router-v4-cannot-get-url) and the reasons for this error discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually).

Most answers suggest adding `devServer.historyApiFallback = true` and `output.publicPath = '/'` in the webpack.config.js file, which implies I also need to run `npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server` and run it using `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server` as suggested in the docs. Doing all of this, nothing happens. In fact, it's worse now because I also can't access my home route of '/'.

So before dropping my current config here, 1) What can I do to fix this? 2) Does it even matter? The webpack-dev-server is obviously for development only so what about production?

My webpack.config.js file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var envFile = require('node-env-file');

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

try {
    envFile(path.join(__dirname, 'config/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.env'))
} catch (e) {
}

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
    entry: [
        'script-loader!foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js',
        './app/app.jsx'
    ],
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                //you don't get to see this
            }
        })
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './public/bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            __dirname,
            'node_modules',
            './app/components',
            './app/api'
        ],
        alias: {
            app: 'app',
            applicationStyles: 'app/styles/app.scss',
            actions: 'app/actions/actions.jsx',
            configureStore: 'app/store/configureStore.jsx',
            reducers: 'app/reducers/reducers.jsx'
            ),
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
                },
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            },
            {
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
                test: /\.(jpg|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/
            },
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                test: /\.scss$/,
                options: {
                    includePaths: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/foundation-sites/scss')
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : 'source-map'
};
```

My app.jsx:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link, HashRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from 'Home';
import Watch from 'Watch';
import About from 'About';
import AddShow from 'AddShow';

var store = require('configureStore').configure();
import firebase from 'app/firebase/';

// Load Foundation
$(document).foundation();

// App css
require('style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!applicationStyles');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/watch" component={Watch}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        <Route path="/addshow" component={AddShow}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up your web server (the one that serves `index.html` with the react app) to redirect all requests to the url of your `index.html` so that react-router can do its job. That's what the suggested change to `webpack.config.js` is doing for webpack-dev-server

In your `webpack.config.js` you need to enable the html plugin so webpack knows where your `index.html` is:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            //you don't get to see this
        }
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'public/index.html' //or wherever your index.html is
    })
],
```

Comment: Yeah I understand that concept, but why isn't it working. The development server states this at startup:
`Project is running at http://localhost:8081/
webpack output is served from /
404s will fallback to /index.html` But yet when I go to `localhost:8081/` I get `Cannot GET /`

Comment: For that error, you need to add the HtmlWebpackPlugin to your `webpack.config.js`, I'm adding that to the answer

Comment: Thanks that addition does help me in getting it to work via the webpack-dev-server, but it doesn't work if I just launch my express server, and I end up with the same problem. The "webpack-dev-server" github page explicitly states that it is for development only, so what do people do for production?

Comment: How are you serving the react app? Are you serving the production build of the react app as a static resource from express? In that case, it should be possible to redirect all requests to your `index.html` and let react-router handle them, i.e. having your `GET /about` route in the backend point to `index.html`