# ReactJS React-router-dom not showing the pages | Cannot GET /{location}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In ReactJS I had a project, before the error I get now, everything was working, and I don't remember I Did something wrong. On my dev localhost, the URL is working, but when I publish on the server and run prod only the index page works, others don't even the default 404 Error page.

Here are the dependencies I use:

```
"dependencies": {
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "local-storage-fallback": "^4.1.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-meta-tags": "^1.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "styled-theming": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

Also here is the ViewPort I use to set up routing:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';


import Home from './pages/Home.js';
import Regulations from './pages/Regulations.js';
import We from './pages/We.js';
import Error from './pages/Error.js';
import List from './pages/List.js';

import Article01 from './stories/Article01.js';


class ViewPort extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/regulations" component={Regulations} />
        <Route path="/we" component={We} />

        <Route path="/feed" component={List} />
        <Route path="/stories/article01" component={Article01} />

        <Route path="/404" component={Error} />
        <Redirect to="/404" />

      </Switch>
    </Router>
  }
}

export default ViewPort;
```

Here is the Webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict';

const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [
          'pug-loader?self'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin()
  ]
};
```

ExpressWebServer Code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Papa = require("papaparse");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    const data = [
        {
            hide: "I remove the data for safety",
        },
    ];
    res.json(data);
    console.log("Data successfully was sent.");
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
    const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/cert.pem', 'utf8');
    const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/chain.pem', 'utf8');
    const credentials = {
        key: privateKey,
        cert: certificate,
        ca: ca
    };

    https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(443, () => {
        console.log('Server is running on port 443');
    });
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(301, {"Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url});
        res.end();
    }).listen(80);
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    app.listen(9000);
} else {
    app.listen(9000);
}
```

It would be nice for someone if can check why this isn't working when I publish, but only on my localhost.

Comment: Does this help: [React-router v4 - cannot GET *url*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209666/react-router-v4-cannot-get-url)

Comment: What web server do you use?

Comment: @Florin I'm using Express, hosting it on Ubuntu 20.4.

Comment: @SethLutske Where can i find "devServer {  historyApiFallback: true }" ?

Comment: Could you share your express server code that serves the page

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I did, does that help?

Comment: The node code was the crucial peice of the pie, @ShubhamKhatri's answer has you covered

Answer (score 1):

The reason you do get 404 is because when you are on a nested route, you request the server to serve you your file but it only sends you index.html for `/` and hence for other paths it gives you 404 since you haven't configured the response.

The solution here is to serve the `index.html` regardless of thee client path so that the routing can then take place on the client side. In case of webpack-dev-server we set `historyApiFallback` to `true`, for a express server you need to send index.html on `app.get('*',`

You can use the below code to make that chaange

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
    app.get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me more the historyApiFallback, how can I fix it?

Comment: you do not need historyApiFallback, what you need is to use `app.get('*', function (req, res) {` Please refer [this(]https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) for more information on what historyApiFallback does

Comment: I think i tried that and didn't work. Shubham.