# React router nested not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create routes in my provider but it doesn't work out for nested levels.

Until one level it is working fine.

Find the code snippet below

```
    render(
  <Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={PageTemplate}>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="/secure" component={BodyTemplate}>
        <Route path="page1" component={Page1}/>
        <Route path="page2" component={Page2}/>
        <Route path="page3" component={Page3}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" component={InvalidPage}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

If I open the URL `localhost:3000/login` it is working fine

but if I give the URL `localhost:3000/secure/page1`
I see the error in the browser console as below

**bundle.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

Kindly help me if there is anything wrong in my router configuration.

Comment: Try `/page1`, `/page2`, `/page3` for the `path` prop.

Comment: I've tried... Its not working.. Even though I Just give the "/" after the first level URL i'm getting the error... eg: "http://localhost:3000/login/" but "http://localhost:3000/login" works fine

Comment: What does your generated index.html file look like? Specifically, how is the bundle.min.js file being included?

Comment: Got the underlying problem i'm refering as <script src="bundle.min.js"></script> changed to <script src="/bundle.min.js"></script> and its working thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected token < error in react router component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718481/unexpected-token-error-in-react-router-component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the script loading from

```
<script src="bundle.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/bundle.min.js"></script>
```

worked as it is trying to load from ur current url when we go to the second level i.e., `localhost:3000/login/bundle.min.js` which is wrong changing it to root url made it working `localhost:3000/bundle.min.js`