# React App returns error after refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

I'm creating a React/Redux app with React Router v4. It has a simple architecture

```
--RootPage    path /
 --HomePage   path /h
   -Gallery   path /h/portfolio
   -Links     path /h/links
   -About     path /h/about
```

Now, every time I refresh, if I'm on second level /h/portfolio, or /h/links, or /h/about, this error net::ERR_ABORTED.

[image]

The refresh works fine if I'm on root level or /h/ level. And I've added `historyApiFallback: true` to devServer so it's not that issue.  It's bit unproductive to have to always go to / root everytime I refresh. What could be wrong here?

Here are my routes

```
const mainRouter=(
    <Wrapper>
<Provider store={store} history={history}>
  <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/h" component={HomePage}/>
       </div>
   </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    </Wrapper>
  )
```

And in HomePage

```
       <main>
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/portfolio`}
          render={ ()=><Gallery {...this.props}/> } />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/about`} render={ ()=><About 
          {...this.props}/> }/>
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/links`} render={ ()=><Links 
          {...this.props}/> }/>

      </main>
```

Comment: In the `render` prop of your HomePage routes, try this callback: `(props)=><About  {...this.props} {...props} />`

Comment: It has nothing to do with `render` as I had `component` before changing it (still cause the problem). This problem started when I added second level path.

Comment: Why are you passing `history` to `Provider` instead of letting `react-router` handle it?

Comment: If I put history in BrowserRouter, it returns an error of BrowserRouter ignoring its history param, so in some tutorials they put it in provider instead. And I believe that in React Router v4, `<BrowderRouter>` has its own built-in history props.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After reproducing the same problem on express server instead of devserver, I got the same error and doing some research, I found this [simple fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718481/unexpected-token-error-in-react-router-component#) to this problem

All I had to do was change the `<script src="js/app.bundle.js"></script>` to `<script src="/js/app.bundle.js"></script>`

Edit: If you use Webpack-html-plugin which I do, it still gives same error, I had to resolve it by adding `output.path.publicPath:"/"` in webpack config file

Comment: A all day to find this answer, thx very mush.
Just to clarify, with webpack `{...,output: {...,publicPath: '/',...},...}`