# GET http://localhost:8080/dist/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, mern

I am new to MERN development. I tried a "Hello World" tutorial to get a basic understanding on MERN.

The tutorial involves Webpack 4, Babel, expressJS and ReactJS.

All works fine but the ES6 compiled bundle.js which was created with Webpack is not getting triggered in the final output.

I get the following error while loading the template.js:

> `GET http://localhost:8080/dist/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" error`

I tried all combination of relative paths but still it is not working.

Please see my `template.js` code below:

```
export default () => {
    return `<!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>MERN Tutorial</title>
          </head>
          <body>          
            <div id="root"></div>            
          </body>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/bundle.js"/>  
        </html>`;
  };
```

Please help me to rectify the issue.

Regards,
Pradeep Selva.

Comment: This is HTML code, which can not be exported using JavaScript files. So, you need to dive little deeper to understand the file structure to start with React.js

Comment: Hi Ashwanmegh, This works when bundled in Webpack. The title "MERN Tutorial" is displayed in the browser and the only thing is bundle.js is not getting called. It throws 404 whereas the file is present in the "dist" folder.

Comment: I think this file is getting created in the `dist` folder if I am not wrong. @Pradeep can you try changing the src to `./bundle.js`

Comment: Yes the file is in dist folder. I tried but is not working.

Comment: when you add the script tag in html:
use this syntax:
`<script type="module" src="/bundle.js"></script>`

Answer (score 4):

Had the same error as well when using React-Router properties.
The problem was caused in my index.html where I load my main reference to my compiled javascript file bundle.js.

I switched:

```
        <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
```

to

```
        <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

And it immediately solved the problem.

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718481/unexpected-token-error-in-react-router-component#) for helping me figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

This error could also be the result of using class names with letters that are not part of basic latin, for instance Ø.