# React Router when passed param doesnt work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```
<Route path='/confirmAccount/:link' component={ConfirmationPage} />
```

this line of code throws error on the browser console ---> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bundle.js:1"

```
<Route path='/confirmAccount' component={ConfirmationPage} />
```

without the '/:link' works fine and renders perfectly.

I have no clue how to fix this with `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bundle.js:1"` as the error message

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'

class ConfirmationPage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        //let loading = this.props.loading;
        let loading = true;
        return (
            <Grid container>
                <Grid>
                    {(loading) && 'Confirming Account. Please wait ....'}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = ({auth}) => {
    const { loading } = auth;
    return ({
        loading
    })
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(ConfirmationPage));
```

UPDATE: solution for this particular problem in answer section

Comment: It is appearing fine here. It is likely coming from your Component or somewhere else

Comment: when i go to 'http://localhost:9000/confirmAccount' the component reders.
but when i go to 'http://localhost:9000/confirmAccount/someString' it fails with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bundle.js:1" error. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the minimum reproducible code of your component?

Comment: added the minimum component to the question

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, so one of solution is to hit npm install maybe will solve problem, second you can search your project and check if publicPath is set to `publicPath: '/',` Good luck :)

Comment: output: { 
   publicPath: '/' // <- adding this has same result.

} 
is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route path='/confirmAccount:hash' component={ConfirmationPage} />
```

if u declare the above as route and use something like below as url

```
localhost:9000/cofirmAccountThisWorks
```

that results in `this.props.match.params.hash => ThisWorks`

I still have no idea why `<Route path='/confirmAccount/:hash' component={ConfirmationPage} />` throw error saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

---

### UPDATE:

---

found the answer in another post -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35302590/11711797

in my index file i had `<script type="text/javascript" src="./bundle.js"></script>` so if i want to use params i have to use `<Route path='/confirmAccount:hash' component={ConfirmationPage} />`

and now if i want to use `<Route path='/confirmAccount/:hash' component={ConfirmationPage} />` i have to change `<script type="text/javascript" src="./bundle.js"></script>` to => `<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>` src="./bundle.js" needs to be src="/bundle.js"