# Passing multiple URL parameters as props using react-router?

Tags: react-router-v4, react-router-dom

When I pass just one parameter as follows, everything works as intended.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={SessionViewer} />
    <Route path="/:sessionID" render={
        (props) => <SessionViewer { ...props }/>
    } />
</Switch>
```

However, when I try to pass multiple (not just one) dynamic URL parameters as props with react-router:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={SessionViewer} />
    <Route path="/:sessionID/:tsFrom/:tsTo" render={
        (props) => <SessionViewer { ...props }/>
    } />
</Switch>
```

The page doesn't load and the following error is thrown:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: could you please share your whole Routes ? where you define all the <Route> Components

Comment: @ThomasBillot sure, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around Stackoverflow for my `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35302590/10124213) that helped resolve the issue. I'll paste it here as well:

The "unexpected token" error can show up for a number of different reasons. I ran into a similar problem, and in my case the problem was that the script tag to load the generated bundle in the html was like so:

```
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

When navigating to a route with a parameter (same thing will happen to a nested route or a route with more than one segment), browser would try to load the script using the wrong url. In my case the route path was 'user/:id', and the browser made a request to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/scripts/app.js` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:3000/scripts/app.js`. The solution was easy, change the script tag to this:

```
<script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: well that's why i asked you to post all your routes ;) you didn't post the `user` ones didn't you? EDIT: i saw that it's a copy pasta from the other post ! either way if it's resolved no problem

Comment: @ThomasBillot The issue was actually in my root-level static html file, where the script was defined, similar to the answer I linked

Comment: Make sure you have a lot of control over you routes, by using `<Switch>` and `exact` property, this will make route matching and debugging 10X easier

Answer (score 2):

I get what you are trying to do but this is not how you do it, react-router actually does this for you in a sense, let me explain:

React-router actually has its own props, and you can `connect` to the router to get those props

Little exemple:

First, Change your routing to this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={SessionViewer} />
    <Route path="/:sessionID/:tsFrom/:tsTo" component={SessionViewer} />
</Switch>
```

this will make sure both routes will render SessionViewer, Then:

1. create a componentDidMount() method in SessionViewer
2. React-Router-Dom will provide you with different props by default if you use `withRouter` method on your component -> Add `export default withRouter(SessionViewer)` to your SessionViewer class
3. Since you have now a connected Class (to the routing) you can access `match` inside your props, this props is created by `react-router` and contains informations about what matched in this route : For exemple `match.params.sessionId` would contains the :sessionId from the route, meaning if I have `/10/from/to`

```
match.params = {
    sessionId: 10,
    tsFrom: from,
    tsTo: to
}
```

4. Now inside you componentDidMount method you can `setState` all the `match.params` you need to make conditionnal rendering for exemple.

Hope it helps, i can go deeper if you need but i rather keep it simple

Comment: Hey, this seems like the idiomatic way to write react routes with props, but it does not solve the ``Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`` error. Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56954957/10124213):