# Vaadin Router: Route Parameters into the address bar not working

Tags: javascript, routes, vaadin, web-component, native-web-component

I am building an application with **Web Components** and use **Vaadin Router** for the routing. I have the following project structure:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script type="module" src="app/app.module.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <mp-app-root></mp-app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.module.js (vaadin router):**

```
(...) multiple imports
import {Router} from '../vaadin-router.js'

// select the DOM node where the route web components are inserted
const outlet = document.querySelector('mp-app-root');

// create a router instance and set the routes config
const router = new Router(outlet);
router.setRoutes([
    {path: '/meals', component: 'mp-meal-module'},
    {path: '/meals/:id', component: 'mp-meal-detail-module'},
]);
```

So far, vaadin router displays every component in the `mp-app-root` tag.

The routes are working fine, when I am calling the URLs via `<a>`-Tags. But if I paste the url into the address bar or on  page reload (e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8081/meals/1`) the components do not load and I am getting the following errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`
```

and

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be similar to the issue described here [Unexpected token < error in react router component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718481/unexpected-token-error-in-react-router-component) (Not a vaadin related).

A solution would be to add a `<base href="/">` to your `index.html` file. The same approach is used in the tutorial of the [Vaadin Router](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/vaadin-router) :)

Comment: wow, I feel kinda stupid now. `<base href="/">` solved the problem. Thank you very much !!!