# Error refresh router react router

Tags: react-router

When I click on the link that contains url `products/new` I can access the new product page and it works fine, but if I refresh the page it returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

How can I resolve this?

### Page product new

```jsx
import React from 'react';

class ProductNew extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div><h1>ProductNew</h1></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = ProductNew;
```

### page products

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { Link }  from 'react-router';

class Products extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div><h1>Products</h1></div>
        <Link to="/products/new">new</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Products;
```

### Page App

```jsx
render((
  <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
       <IndexRoute component={Home} />
       <Route path="/products" component={Products}/>
       <Route path="/products/new" component={ProductNew}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: how does your `Layout` component look like? and is your server supporting browser API?

Comment: @knowbody code in link: https://gist.github.com/mandado/99d95659119571bdb5d0

Comment: i edited above, with link to code

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, my App.js path were relative.
So when I loaded the app page from home path everything worked well, but when I tried to load from a link like yours "/product/new", I received an error like yours. When I put an absolute path, it worked fine.

I was using webpack to bundle the file and webpack-dev-server to run the development env and there is no physical files when you use webpack-dev-server hot loader (by default), it's a thing there is easy to fall in.

---

Edit:
[this guy's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253162/react-router-dynamic-segments-crash-when-accessed) has 2 updates on it, with the same problem as you and has a better answer/info than that I gave to you.

Comment: My case i used  brownserify, i don't know if influence this

Comment: @JorgeRoberto, please up vote if it's the correct answer

Comment: I don't have reputation :/

Comment: @JorgeRoberto can you at least set it as the correct answer?

Comment: how ? i beginner in stackoverflow rs.

Comment: Correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253162/react-router-dynamic-segments-crash-when-accessed

Answer (score 0):

whe you are using nested path for component Like http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/myprojects then you should must add absolute path for your css and js in main index file..for example in laravel index.php.blade file add absolute path Like this: <'script  src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}">
</'script>