# dynamic-segments using basename on the server side - React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I have the following code written into my `server.js` for isomorphic rendering.

```
import { match, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';
import createHistory from 'react-router/lib/createMemoryHistory';

import createHistory from 'react-router/lib/createMemoryHistory';
import { useBasename } from 'history'; 
import getRoutes from './routes';


const client = new ApiClient(req);
const memoryHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
    basename: '/in'
  });
const store = createStore(memoryHistory, client);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(memoryHistory, store);

match({ history, routes: getRoutes(store), location: req.originalUrl }, (error, redirectLocation,   renderProps) => {
    console.log(error, redirectLocation, renderProps)
    // undefined, undefined, undefined returned
})
```

Now when I tweak the params a little to check where the issues may be, I made the following updates.

`match({ history, routes: getRoutes(store) }, (error, redirectLocation,   renderProps)`

I ended up getting the following log:

```
null { pathname: '/in/leagues',
  search: '',
  hash: '',
  state: null,
  action: 'REPLACE',
  key: 'meh7oq',
  basename: '/in',
  query: {} } undefined
```

Is there some parameter I am missing or is this base name not meant for server side rendering.

I also tried using the `useBasename` function in history

```
const memoryHistory = useBasename(createHistory)({
    basename: '/in'
});
```