# React doesn't render on page refresh or manual URL entry

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've made two components. one is Articles.js and the another one is article.js. The router is in app.js. here is code from app.js:

```
 <Router>
      <Switch>
        
        <Route exact path="/articles" component={Articles}>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/article/:id" component={Article}/>
  
      </Switch>
      
    </Router>
```

I've made link to `"article/:id"` in Articles component. If I click on the link in articles page, it works just fine, however, If I try to reload the page or manually enter id, for eg: "article/23", it will not render anything at all on the page.
I found some results on internet, but, most of them are either not relevant or are using hooks, which I cannot use with class components.

In componentDidMount function of Article compnent i am calling getData function which fetches data from the server and then after verfiying the response sends data here to this function :

```
initFunction = (ar)=>{

        let data = ar.map(d=>{
            return(
                <tr><td>{d.id}</td><td>{d.title}</td><td>{moment(d.created_on).format('MMMM,Do YYYY')}</td><td>
                    <Link to={`article/${d.id}`}>Edit</Link> | 
                    <Link to={`article/delete/${d.id}`}> Delete</Link>
                    </td></tr>
            )
        })
        this.setState({
            tableData:<>{data}</>
        })
    }
```

And this function just generates table rows and save them in state, which I use in render function to display the data. If I go to article page through this link, it will work fine but same link will not render anything if type it manually or reload it.

Here are the components I am importing in my component:

```
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { instanceOf } from 'prop-types';
import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
import moment from 'moment'
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console when this behaviour occurs?

Comment: @JakeC when i visit page through link I am not getting any error in console, however, on reloading I am getting :  Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: What is the server side ? Node app ? show us how you handle the requests there, as it looks like an issue of what gets served by the server.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli This page is not fetching any data from server, its just empty RN. I'm just displaying ID to check

Comment: could you show the **Articles** component

Comment: @miraj I will update my question

Comment: where is the `Link` that takes to `/article/:id`?

Comment: @miraj oh, I updated the code

Comment: @DhruvChopra i am not talking about fetching data, i am asking where the is the actual page located/hosted and how is the page served/loaded.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli RN frontend is on my local system and backend is on a server

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is probably that your server is not set up to serve your app on the `/article` route.

When you click on the link in your app then react-router does not actually request make a request to your server for that route. Instead it updates the url and re-renders your app which picks up the new route.

When you load the route directly (such as on page reload or manually typing in the url bar) the react router has not been loaded yet. Instead the browser just blindly makes a request to that route. This is when your app is failing.

Comment: This is a great explanation of the problem, but you have not provided a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. I found the solution from this thread.

[react-router dynamic segments crash when accessed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253162/react-router-dynamic-segments-crash-when-accessed/34526066#34526066)

added  into the  of my index.html

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

what is initState of id, I think you need to store id to state and set initState is empty string, it work for me.

```
const [myId, setMyId] = useState("")
```

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and explanation or delete it

Answer (score 0):

I added `<base href="/" />` into the `<head>` of my index.html and it worked.