# How manage express routes with param?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a basic question but it block me from 2 days now. **I'm learing NodeJs**. I'm facing a problem that I didn't meet in dev mode. So I'm confuse.

I have two routes on my **server.js**

```
const governmentCreateRouter = require('./routes/GovernmentCreate');
app.use("/governmentCreate", governmentCreateRouter);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

If I understand how it work when I use this url `https://mondomaine/GovernmentCreate`, express catch with `app.use("/governmentCreate", governmentCreateRouter);` my url and route to `./routes/GovernmentCreate`.

**GovernmentCreate.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { GovernmentCreate } = require('../models');

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    //some code
});

router.get("/byId/:id", async (req, res) => {
 //some code
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  //some code
});
```

Now, I have a page name **GovernmentId.js**

```
const [governmentList, setGovernmentList] = useState([]);

let { id } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {

    axios.get(`https://monDomain/governmentCreate/byId/${id}`)
        .then((res) => {

            setGovernmentList([res.data]);

        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}, []);

//return ...code
```

This page is call with url https://monDomain/gouvernement/:id. the `:id` is a number that allow to search index in my database.

**app.js**

```
<BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/a-propos" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/gouvernement/:id" element={<GovernmentId />} />
          </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

But when I put this url in my browser, it return me an **error**

[image]

```
La feuille de style https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/gouvernement/static/css/main.3eea6a9b.css n’a pas été chargée car son type MIME, « text/html », n’est pas « text/css ».
Le script à l’adresse « https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/gouvernement/static/js/main.02a475ac.js » a été chargé alors que son type MIME (« text/html ») n’est pas un type MIME JavaScript valide.
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

I understand that my url (https://monDomain/gouvernement/:id) is catched by .get('/*' on my server.js. But why it don't return html, css, js page and after actived the useEffect ?

Comment: i can't read the language your error is throwing. nonetheless by looking at your problem it seems to me as cors problem.---> https://stackabuse.com/handling-cors-with-node-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solve my issu** with the code below. I add into my **package.json** this line

```
"homepage": "https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/",
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a rendering problem to me, since if you follow links it actually works. Here is what I mean:

- Go on https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/gouvernement-galerie
- Select the gouvernment n 8, it will take you to https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/gouvernement/8 (which works)
- Refresh the page and it doesn't work anymore

This is a problem that occurs also in other frameworks, and I believe that the Update number 2 in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253162/react-router-dynamic-segments-crash-when-accessed/34526066#34526066) question can help you solve your issue.

##### Edit 1

You have to modify your `app.js` file:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';

const history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
    basename: '/' 
});

// ...other code

<BrowserRouter history={history}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/a-propos" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/gouvernement/:id" element={<GovernmentId />} />
          </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: thank for your answer. You excatly get my problem. Where did you add 
`const history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
    basename: '/'
});`
of yout answer 2 you linked ?

Comment: I edited my answer to add where to add the history part

Comment: Thank you to edit your post. I did like you do but when I want to `npm run build` it return after fews seconds `Attempted import error: 'useRouterHistory' is not exported from 'react-router' (imported as 'useRouterHistory').`.
I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: And what utility of `import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';` ? I don't appear in your code?

Comment: It is the same thing to do it : https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter.
If yes, unfortunatly that doesn't work.